# Store to array the id of all elements with a given class name

Tags: javascript

```
function storeid(){
    var className = document.getElementsByClassName('Jicon');
    var classnameCount = className.length;
    var IdStore = new Array();
    for(var j = 0; j < classnameCount; j++){
        IdStore = classnameCount.id[j];
    }

}
```

My intention is to get the id of all elements with a specific class name and store them in array.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/50fk50pn/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get all the ids in IdStore  array.

```js
function storeid(){
    var className = document.getElementsByClassName('Jicon');
    var classnameCount = className.length;
    var IdStore = new Array();
    for(var j = 0; j < classnameCount; j++){
        debugger;
        IdStore.push(className[j].id);
    }
    alert(IdStore.length);
}
storeid();
```

```html
<div class="Jicon" id="displayImage1">image1</div>
<div class="Jicon" id="displayImage2">image2</div>
<div class="Jicon" id="displayImage3">image3</div>
<div class="Jicon" id="displayImage4">image4</div>
```

Comment: Thanks is all i wanted ~

Answer (score 1):

I prefer querySelectorAll for this kind of things, since getElementsByClassName returns a live list, which could mess up other logic if you add/remove elements with that class.

```
var ids = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.Jicon')).map(function ( element ) {
    return element.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need few changes like following:

You must use `className` as it's actual array of elements which is returned by your query `getElementsByClassName()`

You must use `.push()` to add item into the array

```
for(var j = 0; j < classnameCount; j++){
    IdStore.push(className[j].id); // use className instead of classnameCount
}
```

### [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/50fk50pn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function storeid(){
    var className = document.getElementsByClassName('Jicon');
    return className.map(function(cur){
         return cur.id
    });
}

document.write( JSON.stringify(storeid()) )
```

```html
<div class="Jicon" id="displayImage1">image1</div>
<div class="Jicon" id="displayImage2">image2</div>
<div class="Jicon" id="displayImage3">image3</div>
<div class="Jicon" id="displayImage4">image4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function storeid(){
    var className = document.getElementsByClassName('Jicon');
    var classnameCount = className.length;
    var IdStore = new Array();
    for(var j = 0; j < classnameCount; j++){
        IdStore[j] = className[j].id;
    }
    alert(IdStore.length);
}
```

here goes your code. Voila!!
NOTE: remove the alert in code.